# virt-sysprep error Domain not found: no domain with matching name

Tags: server, virtualization, 22.04, kvm-virtualization

I just installed libguestfs-tools so i can use virt-sysprep -d

i start it and this is what i got. can someone help me ?
im using ubuntu 22.04 server

```
root@ctest:~/ssdd/isos# virt-sysprep -v -x -d out.raw  
[   0.0] Examining the guest ...  
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose true  
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose = 0  
libguestfs: trace: set_network false  
libguestfs: trace: set_network = 0  
libguestfs: trace: add_domain "out.raw" "readonly:false" "allowuuid:true" "readonlydisk:ignore" "discard:besteffort"  
libguestfs: opening libvirt handle: URI = NULL, auth = default+wrapper, flags = 0  
libguestfs: successfully opened libvirt handle: conn = 0x55daeba64030  
libguestfs: trace: add_domain = -1 (error)  
virt-sysprep: error: libguestfs error: no libvirt domain called 
‘out.raw’: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'out.raw'  
libguestfs: trace: close  
libguestfs: closing guestfs handle 0x55daeba5f8e0 (state 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to have a previously created VM with domain name `out.raw`.
If you want to list what VMs virt thinks you have use the `virt -list` command:

```
doug@s19:~/system-info$ virsh list
 Id   Name   State
--------------------
```

But I forgot, I don't actually have any VM running at the moment, so to list inactive domains:

```
doug@s19:~/system-info$ virsh list --inactive
 Id   Name      State
--------------------------
 -    desk-ff   shut off
 -    desk-hh   shut off
 -    desk-ii   shut off
 -    serv-xx   shut off
```

Or to list both active and inactive domains all at once:

```
doug@s19:~/system-info$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name      State
--------------------------
 -    desk-ff   shut off
 -    desk-hh   shut off
 -    desk-ii   shut off
 -    serv-xx   shut off
```

My VM images are:

```
doug@s19:~/system-info$ ls -l ~/vm
total 87258752
-rw------- 1 root root 53695545344 Jun  8 08:43 desk-ff.img
-rw------- 1 root root 53695545344 Jun  8 08:40 desk-hh.img
-rw------- 1 root root 53695545344 Jun 17 06:58 desk-ii.img
-rw------- 1 root root 53695545344 Jun 20  2021 serv-xx.img
```

Comment: i will try to make a vm and add the .raw disk to it.